# Android - Decimal Formatter

Tags: android

I've try this in my device and work fine. But, in some Android device, the symbol is in wrong place. This is my code :

```
public static String convertToRupiah(String priceBeforeConverted){

    //manual setting separator, because currently RUPIAH is NOT supported
    DecimalFormat formatter = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
    DecimalFormatSymbols formatRupiah = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
    formatRupiah.setCurrencySymbol("Rp ");
    formatRupiah.setMonetaryDecimalSeparator(',');
    formatRupiah.setGroupingSeparator('.');
    formatter.setDecimalFormatSymbols(formatRupiah);

    Double price = StringFormatter.isNullOrEmpty(priceBeforeConverted) ? 0.00 : Double.valueOf(priceBeforeConverted) ;
    String conversionResult = formatter.format(price);

    if(conversionResult.endsWith(",00"))
        conversionResult = conversionResult.substring(0, conversionResult.length()-3);

    return conversionResult;
}
```

[image]

expected result is : Rp 25.000,00

Comment: do you want 25.000,00 i.e after 25. you need values or Rp 25 ?

Comment: String pattern = "Rp ###,###.### ";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);

String format = decimalFormat.format(25000000.08);
System.out.println(format);

//Try this.

Comment: just move the symbol bro @SyedHamzaHassan i.e Rp 25.000

Comment: I have updated code in Answer.

Comment: hmmm in my device, it works perfectly bro with code above, but in my friends device, it generate result like in the picture @SyedHamzaHassan

Comment: Please tell device name ? Os Version ?

Comment: my device is Xiaomi Redmi Note 5A, and my friend's device Xiaomi Note 5 bro @SyedHamzaHassan

Comment: both OS version is nougat

Comment: let me clear one more thing does both have same locale settings ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String pattern = "Rp ###,###.000 ";
DecimalFormat decimalFormat = new DecimalFormat(pattern);

String format = decimalFormat.format(25.000);
System.out.println(format);
```

--Try this, your zeros after decimal place will not miss. Output of this code is.

> Rp 25.000

Let me know if anything is not clear.

Comment: @HusniKamal Sure.

Comment: Thanks bro! @Syed